# ListBox selected index is lost after PostBack in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, listbox, postback, selectedindex

I've got an issue with a ListBox in ASP.NET application: after manual selection, an event "SelectedIndexChanged" fires, but its handler cannot keep neither the selected index nor the selected item. The index is always equal to '-1' :( I enabled AutoPostBack, so that the Text property of a TextBox could be updated.

In this code snippet, the **SelectedItem** is always **null** :(

```
protected void ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox3.SelectedItem != null)
        TextBox6.Text = ListBox3.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Here is the description of a control:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" 
     runat="server" Height="283px" 
     style="margin-left: 28px; margin-top: 6px;" Width="156px" 
     DataSourceID="StacjeNaTrasie"
     DataTextField="Nazwa_Stacji" DataValueField="Nazwa_Stacji" 
     onselectedindexchanged="ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True">
</asp:ListBox>
```

It looks like the PostBack triggers another selectionIndexChange event and the selected index is again set to '-1'. How could I keep the selected one?

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: How you are populating your listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its

`onselectedindexchanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"` ?

isn't it suppose to be

`onselectedindexchanged="ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged"` ?

Comment: did u set a default selected item to be -1?

Comment: try this- add a new item to the list with a value != NULL. also, set it to selected (in edit items), and see if it changes the result

Comment: Just setting the first item from my collection as selected after dataBinding ( performed at PageLoad when it's not a PostBack ) solved the case;) Thank you so much!